# Planner integrations don't show current plans

Tags: office365, microsoft-planner, microsoft-teams

Right now I'm working in Microsoft Teams and I'm trying to utilize the Microsoft Planner integration.  I already have two plans in Microsoft Planner.  However, when I add the tab for Planner in Teams, the only option is to create a new plan.

[image]

For testing, I went ahead and created the new plan. It did show up in Planner.  Also, if I remove it from Teams and try to add another planner, it now shows up as an option, but it is the only one available.

Essentially, plans I create in Planner do not show up in Teams.  Plans I create in Teams show up in both.  I also had a similar experience with Sharepoint integration.

**How can I get MS Teams to show my other plans??**

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the relationship between Teams and Groups. Each "Team" is an extension of an ["Office 365 Group"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2) (also known as a "Unified Group" within Azure Active Diretory).

The Plans that show up for a given Team are all owned by the underlying Group that the Team is tied to. Think of the Group as another User, and just as you and I own our own Plans, so does a Group owns.

The Plans that show up in Planner include both Plans owned by Teams/Groups you are a member/owner of as well as Plans you own yourself. In other words, Planner surfaces all of the Plans you have access too. And just as you cannot see *my* plans, your Team cannot see *your* plans.